# Phlex Docker image is not reachable via http

Tags: windows, docker

I'm installing [Phlex](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitalhigh/phlex/) with Docker on my windows 10 PC.
I have run the command `docker create --name=Phlex --net=host -v /g/phlex:/config -e HTTPPORT=5666 -e HTTPSPORT=5667 -e FASTCGIPORT=9000 -p 5666:80 -p 5667:443 --privileged digitalhigh/phlex`

and the container is created.
When I start the container (`docker start Phlex`), it runs successfully.

However, when I try to connect to `localhost:5666/5667` it refuses to connect. What am I doing wrong here? Phlex `EXPOSES` ports 80 and 443 and the only suspicious thing in the log is `ip: either "to" is duplicate, or "224.0.0.0" is garbage` and I have no idea what that means.

This is my full workflow I have done nothing else.

Comment: Post the logs of your container to the question. Also use `ipconfig` and get the docker IP. Instead of trying `localhost:5666` try the `<dockerip>:5666`

Comment: Ok, `ipconfig` gives me an ip address of `10.0.75.1` which, when used, still gives me nothing

Comment: I also get nothing returned when I run `docker port Phlex`

Comment: The image might not be running only. Try `docker ps` and check container is running or not

Comment: The image is running. I can exec into bash within it

Comment: Try `http://localhost` or `http://10.0.75.1`, i think i see the problem now

Comment: Both refuse to connect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153389/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-lucidnonsense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
docker run --name=Phlex -p 5666:5666 -p 5667:5667 -v /g/phlex:/config -e HTTPPORT=5666 -e HTTPSPORT=5667 -e FASTCGIPORT=9000 --privileged digitalhigh/phlex
```

When you use `--net=host` you should not be using port mappings. So no `-p X:Y` should be there. And when you want to do port mappings don't use `--net=host`

Also I looked at the image, it run nginx and fpm in the same image. So if you are testing phlex and or its not a core thing you work on, then you can use this image. Else you should build one of your own `Dockerfile`. This image is not one the optimized images as such